# Написать компаратор по двум полям

Tags: java, compare

Есть объекты с двумя полями - String uuid и String fullName.
Изначально компаратор был написан для сортировки по uuid,

```
public int compare(Resume o1, Resume o2) {
            return o1.getUuid().compareTo(o2.getUuid());
        }
```

теперь его нужно переписать с условием возможного совпадения fullName у разных uuid. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

```
Comparator<Resume> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Resume::getUuid)
                                          .thenComparing(Resume::getFullName);
```